# running loop with Matlab commands on background BASH #3

Tags: bash, matlab, background

I managed to run Matlab on background with the help of the website below:

http://www.stat.osu.edu/computer-support/programming/background-jobs

I am performing the loop:

```
for ((i = 1; i <= 5; i++)); do
    echo $i>i.txt;
    matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay <script.m &> dummy.out &
done
```

in the script there is a part :

```
fid=fopen( 'a:\folder\i.txt');'];
iter=str2double(fgets(fid))
myfunction(iter,a,b,c)
```

the function line at myfunction.m is

```
myfunction(num,a,b,c)
```

this function saves a file with a name that is also changing according to the value of 'num'

meaning, the output will be: myfile1.mat for the 1st command, myfile2 for the 2nd command etc.

when I'm running the commands without the loop

```
echo 1>i.txt;
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay <script.m &> dummy.out &
echo 2>i.txt;
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay <script.m &> dummy.out &

etc...
```

there are no problems and the output is good

when I'm running the loop the only file i'm getting is myfile5.mat

I've changed the code so that the input will be myfunction(i1,a,b,c), myfunction(i2,a,b,c)... but the results remain the same.

I think that beacuse the saving part is at the end of the function (which runs for a long time) somehow for all the functions 'num' is 5 (the loop is finished much faster than the calculations).

any ideas? tnx

Comment: Try putting a `sleep 1` after the call to matlab inside your loop, I think you're right in your diagnosis. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, tnx, I tried sleep 10 before and after the call for matlab, it was'nt enough, and it won't be a good solution because the duration of the function's work varies from call to call, any other suggustions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem,

it is quite simple, all I had to do is export the variables to the enviroment and them read them in the MATLAB script

```
for ((i = 1; i <= 5; i++)); do
     export i
     matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay <script.m &> dummy.out &
done
```

and in the script.m

```
iter=str2double(getenv('i'))
myfunction(iter,a,b,c)
```

works good!

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that you run jobs with the same file, as it runs in background mode, first the file contains "1", after that "2", "3", "4", "5", and only after that the first script start evaluating (and see already "5" in the file, not "1").

You are now trying to pass a parameter to a function through file, right? I just wonder, why not passing the parameter to the function itself? Running a number of functions in Matlab in parallel (in background mode) described here, for example: http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/166876

Comment: the number of iterations can go up, let's say to a hundred, how would u sugguest to imply this method over the code above? tnx

Comment: You can create background workers in a loop. Just create `funList` as an list of the same functions, but `dataList = {1, 2, .., 100}`, and use `matlabpool open 100`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the ampersand (`&`) sign after the MATLAB call - what is happening is that the loop starts running, puts the value 1 into i.txt, then **forks off** a MATLAB process, then the loop runs again, puts the value 2 into i.txt, then forks off **another** MATLAB process, and so on. Now MATLAB takes a while to start, and this loop is really quick since it's not waiting around for the MATLAB call to finish, so by the time the first MATLAB instance finally finishes, the loop is long finished and the value in i.txt is 5 for all the calls.

Short version: Remove the `&` sign :)

That will make MATLAB run and finish before continuing with the loop.

Comment: tnx for the diagnosis. I would but the loop goes much more than 5 and after all the processes are at the background I need to connect to other servers and run the same thing. is there another solution u suggest?

Comment: look into systems that are designed to support large-scale multi-processing managment, Hadoop is one, there are numerous others. You won't be able to run a 100 Matlab sessions at once on any PC like hardware I'm aware of, which is what would happen given the code you've presented so far. Good luck.

Comment: You can pass MATLAB the parameter directly, or name the input files differently and pass the filename as a parameter, or you can make directories, put an i.txt in each of them, and in each loop cd to that directory and start up MATLAB there. I agree with @shellter that a single PC wouldn't be able to handle 100 MATLAB instances. It would just stall your system and thresh like crazy.